# Liquid HTML - sizing issue

Tags: html, liquid-layout

Why is the red box not  the same size as the green box? (I have to have the absolute position as I'm overlaying two images)

What am I doing wrong?

```
<div style="position: relative; float: left; width: 300px; background: red; border: 10px solid red">
    <div id="holder" style="position: relative;">
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; background: green">
            <img src="image" width="100" height="100"></div>
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; background: green">
            <img src="overlay" width="100" height="100"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What effect exactly are you trying to achieve? Without knowing this we can't possibly tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Any reason why there's no height specified on the outer div? Since your inner elements are positioned absolutely and removed from the normal flow of the document, the outer div has no idea how large they are.

Comment: Pretty much exactly what I said in the description!

I have two images which are overlayed, they're in a floating div, and I want that div to stretch to the size of the images.

Comment: Do you understand what positioning them absolutely does and what "removed from the normal flow of the document" means?

Comment: No need to resort to sarcasm, or anything similar, @TheBounder. You have two images positioned absolutely, but why do they BOTH need to be absolute? Surely, if they're both the same size (which they are in this example), you can position one relative and one absolute, can you not?

Comment: Cheers @ClarkeyBoy! @j08691 - thanks for the help - if you need any pointers with  graphic design from this decade for your site, I'd be happy to lend a hand.

Comment: @TheBounder - no problem. And if you need help with CSS 101 drop me a line. I'll be sure to double bill you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to give the holder div the same height as images have. I assume that you have some specific two overlapping images so you know the size of them.